# Can the UID on a RFID chip be overriden?

Tags: security, overriding, nfc, uuid, rfid

I'm working on a project where I use RFID chips to identify different units, using the UID on the chip. But a security issue came to mind. Is it anyway possible the override or spoof the UID of a RFID chip? And how is the UID stored on the RFID chip? Is it hardwired(ROM) or is it a part of the general read/write memory storage?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what RFID chip you use, the ID of the chip may be:

1. Non-unique: the set of 32-bit UID is nearly exhausted. Manufacturers are starting to re-use older unique IDs. A remaining range of 32-bit IDs has been designated as non-unique in the ISO 14443 standard and cannot be relied upon as being unique.
2. Randomly generated: it will be different every time the chip is accessed
3. Overwritable: certain products have a configurable ID
4. Spoofed: certain devices can emulate certain RFID chips, including the ID.

In general, it is good security practice not to rely only on the ID of the chip to be unique for the security of your system, I would say. Depending on what security needs you have, you may want to use an RFID chip that offers proper authentication functionality.